# Assembly: Error[66]: Segment too long (max is ffff)

Tags: assembly, embedded, msp430, iar

I created a new Assembly project in which I will write a test.s file and just link against an entire app and its mocks (both of those are in Assembly too). The test.s file is mostly empty so far, yet when now compiling everything it just says "Error[66]: Segment too long (max is ffff) "

The error points to some random line in the application code.

The line in question is a jz instruction to a label in that file. If I comment that jz instruction it just complains about the next jz instructions which is 15 lines lower in the file. Is this somehow related to the jump instruction and not the code size or so?

And the project of the application compiles just fine on its own. I also copied the application's linker file, which defines memory segments
there are no mocks or whatever so far, just an app and a new test.s file containing a main with its setup

How does one go about debugging such a cryptic error to figure out what causes this issue?

I randomly tried putting the origing to 00000h, 02000h or 0ffffh but none of those made any difference or gave a different error.

Thanks

EDIT:

Some more info:

- for MSP430F148
- IAR workbench IDE 6.50.1

Comment: MSP430's jump instructions have a range of  "−511 to +512 words relative to the PC value at the jump instruction" using a 10-bit offset (http://www.ece.uah.edu/~milenka/cpe323-10S/lectures/cpe323msp430_ISA.pdf).  Could you be trying to jump too far, to some symbol defined in another file?  Probably that's not it, I don't know that toolchain at all but `0xfff` wouldn't be something you'd expect to see if you were hitting the limit of a 10-bit scaled displacement.

Comment: But you say you're trying to link against a "an entire app"?  Can you produce a [mcve] with minimal stuff to link against?  It doesn't have to be a usable program at all, just something that demonstrates the build error, so try dramatically stripping down the size of what you're linking to, in case that changes anything.  And if not, you'll maybe end up with a [mcve] small enough to actually include in your question in a code block.

Comment: The segment too long error is not about the content of your code it is about the size of it. The error tells you that the you try to put more than 64k in the same segment and that this is not possible.

Comment: @Johan sorry for this stupid question... why is specifically 64k not possible? Where does the 64k number come from?

Comment: @tifejed833_95ta.com The maximum size of a segment depends on two things, the hardware and the linker configurations. I have no real knowledge about the msp430 chip but if memory is divided into 64k banks it may not be possible to have larger segments. It may also be that the linker configuration file only defines 64k blocks, either in general or specifically for this segment.

Comment: @tifejed833_95ta.com 64k is also the largest size that can be adressed using 16-bit pointers.

Comment: @Johan shouldn't it then be 65k536, because you know 2^16 = 65.536, not 64k. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @tifejed833_95ta.com When talking about memory 1k = 1024 bytes.